# Lorentz Transformation Notation

Tags: special-relativity

A frame $s'$ is moving with velocity $v_1$ in the x-direction with respect to a frame $s$. $s''$ is moving with velocity $v_2$ in the y-direction with respect to $s'$. I know to multiply the matrix containing the boost in x by the matrix containing the boost in y for the cumulative effect. However, the problem I'm working on says to find the matrix $\Lambda ^ {\alpha''}_\mu$ from the frame $s$ to $s''$. To get this specific matrix, would I multiply the y-boost matrix by the x-boost matrix, or would I multiply the x-boost matrix by the y-boost matrix?

I.e. should I do (in $c=1$ units)

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{\gamma_{2}} & {0} & {-v_{2} \gamma_{2}} & {0} \\ {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} \\ {-v_{2} \gamma_{2}} & {0} & {\gamma_{2}} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} & {1}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{\gamma_{1}} & {-v_{1} \gamma_{1}} & {0} & {0} \\ {-v_{1} \gamma_{1}} & {\gamma_{1}} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} & {1}\end{array}\right]$$

or

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{\gamma_{1}} & {-v_{1} \gamma_{1}} & {0} & {0} \\ {-v_{1} \gamma_{1}} & {\gamma_{1}} & {0} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} & {1}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{\gamma_{2}} & {0} & {-v_{2} \gamma_{2}} & {0} \\ {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} \\ {-v_{2} \gamma_{2}} & {0} & {\gamma_{2}} & {0} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} & {1}\end{array}\right]$$

Also, are the entries in my matrices correct for the respective boosts?

Comment: Think about how the matrices act on a vector of coordinates. Is the vector on the left or on the right of the matrix?

Comment: Answer to last question: yes.

Comment: The vector (t,x,y,z) is on the right on top and the left on bottom I believe? So the top option is $\Lambda^{\alpha''}_\mu$?

Comment: Yes, the top option represents boosting *first* by $v_1\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ and *then* by $v_2\hat{\mathbf{y}}$.